# How website name get resolved?

Tags: networking, dns, gateway

I'm using Internet via a usb datacard on Ubuntu 12.04. I never configure domain name server.

My question is how website name get resolved?

- Is there a inbuilt domain name server in system? if not than how are website name get resolved?
- What happen inside a system when I type a name of website and press enter?
- I don't have any router than what is my default gateway?

Please explain me the complete process.

Comment: How about [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PC is not a DNS server, but it does keep a cache for previous queries. You usually have the IP of your DNS server pushed to you by your ISP (Internet Service Provider) when you connect via the datacard along with your IP address, default gateway and other network info. This is done with the DHCP protocol usually.

You can see what DNS you have configured by opening a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and typing

> cat /etc/resolv.conf

if you want to see your default gateway you can view it by using

> cat /etc/network/interfaces

or by using

> ip route show

and look for the line starting with **default**

Comment: thank you  for answer. pls can you explain how dhcp work

Comment: sure. If We're talking about a home LAN, the DHCP server is usually on the gateway router. When your PC is booting up, it checks to see if its network interfaces have static IP addresses or dynamic. If it's the latter case, the PC (or other device) sends a DHCP request to the server. The server is preconfigured with default gateway IP, IP pool (range of IPs to lease to clients) network mask and DNS server IP which it sends to the client in a DHCP response.